# Replace double slash with single slash in import.io XPath selector

Tags: html, xml, xpath, import.io

I am using import.io to scrape some pages.  I came across a page that uses internal hrefs like this: `http://domain.com//Event` - notice the double slash after the domain name.  From my research, this is done for SEO purposes but I need to get the url without those double slashes, so it returns `http://domain.com/Event`.

I am trying to use XPath (which I'm very new to) and I can get the link fine with: `//a[contains(@class, 'event-info-btn')]//@href`.

My next step was to try `fn:repace()` with this: `fn:replace(//a[contains(@class, 'event-info-btn')]//@href, 'http://domain.com//', 'http://domain.com/')`.  This isn't working - nothing is returned.

I'm not sure if my implementation is bad, or if import.io just doesn't support this.

- I'll also note the reason why I'm trying to do this: import.io is failing on all of the urls. If I manually remove the slash and try again, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that import.io [**claims**](http://import.io's%20claim%20that%20they%20support%20XPath%202.0) to support XPath 2.0.

### Problem

You probably mean `/@href` rather than `//@href`, but that's not the real problem.

Your XPath is returning a sequence of `href` attributes where `replace()` is expecting a string.

### Solution

For this HTML,

```
<div>
  <a class="event-info-btn" href="http://domain.com//1">one</a>
  <a class="event-info-btn" href="http://domain.com//2">one</a>
  <a class="event-info-btn" href="http://domain.com//3">one</a>
</div>
```

this XPath,

```
for $href in //a[contains(@class, 'event-info-btn')]/@href 
    return replace($href, 'http://domain.com//', 'http://domain.com/')
```

will return

```
http://domain.com/1
http://domain.com/2
http://domain.com/3
```

as requested.

---

### Update

> This doesn't work in import.io and I'm having trouble finding a
>   fiddle-like site to test it.

You can see this working **[here](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable+all+extensions&data=%3Cdiv%3E%0A++%3Ca+class%3D%22event-info-btn%22+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%2F1%22%3Eone%3C%2Fa%3E%0A++%3Ca+class%3D%22event-info-btn%22+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%2F2%22%3Eone%3C%2Fa%3E%0A++%3Ca+class%3D%22event-info-btn%22+href%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%2F3%22%3Eone%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&extract=for+%24href+in+%2F%2Fa[contains(%40class%2C+%27event-info-btn%27)]%2F%40href+%0A++++return+replace(%24href%2C+%27http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%2F%27%2C+%27http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F%27)&extract-kind=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous)**.

> Import.io, it seems, only allows you to input one line of xpath.

You might try putting the XPath on a single line, then:

```
for $href in //a[contains(@class, 'event-info-btn')]/@href return replace($href, 'http://domain.com//', 'http://domain.com/')
```

**If that doesn't work, then [import.io's claim that they support XPath 2.0](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/341182-xpaths-regex) is not correct.**

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes.  This doesn't work in import.io and I'm having trouble finding a fiddle-like site to test it.  Import.io, it seems, only allows you to input one line of xpath.  I tried to wrap the loop in parens and then use brackets but that didn't work either.  I'll keep digging into import.io to see if I'm just missing how to use a loop in the interface.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've used your link to confirm it does work on one line as well.  It still doesn't work in import.io but that's an issue I'll have to address with them.